# Is there any way to perform delegation through a function?

Tags: swift

With purposes avoiding repetition, how can you convert something like this:

```
 self.upperTextField.delegate = self
 self.lowerTextField.delegate = self
```

Into:

```
 func setDelegates(textField: UITextField){
        textField.delegate = self
        print("delegates set")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your function to accept an array of `UITextField` objects:

```
func setDelegates(delegate: UITextFieldDelegate, textFields: [UITextField]) {
    for textField in textFields {
        textField.delegate = delegate
    }
    print("delegates set")
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
setDelegates(self, textFields: [upperTextField, lowerTextField])
```

Comment: Since you don't use the return value, you can use `forEach` or a simple for-in-loop instead of `map`

Comment: How is a for loop simpler than map here? They use the same number of lines of code.

Comment: It's just the semantics: `map` maps values i.e. you feed it something, it applies a function to the values and returns them. But that's not what you're doing here, you just call a method on those objects and don't return them.

Comment: I see your point. Although map does work here, a for loop is clearer. I've updated my answer. Thanks.